# Неверная компоновка элементов

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

У меня огромнейшая проблема с версткой, уже 100й раз себя перепроверяю, вроде все верно, а все равно не так, как надо. Если я ввожу в один из блоков `div` текст, то он идет по всему экрану, а не только по своему блоку. Подскажите, что и как. Прилагаю коды, скрины в отдел + папку с проектом (архив).

В общем, у меня такая структура сайта:

`Обертка
Шапка
Меню левое l Контент l Меню правое
Блок "clear"
Foter`

Скрин этого добра прилагаю.

Код HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title> </title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="script/js/lib/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="script/js/equalHeight.js" type="text/javascript"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div> 
        <div id="left_sidebar"></div> 
        <div id="right_sidebar"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Код CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Разметка сайта*/

body,html {
marging:0;
padding:0;
}

#wrapper{
marging: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}

#header{
outline: 1px #096 solid;
height: 125px;  
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#left_sidebar{
outline: 1px #096 solid;
height:500px;
float:left;     
width: 160px;
}

#content{
outline: 1px #096 solid;
margin:0 170px 10px 170px;
height:500px;
width: 630px;   
}

#right_sidebar{
outline: 1px #096 solid;
float:right;
height:500px;
width: 160px;
}

#clear{
clear:both;     
}

#footer{
outline: 1px #096 solid;
height:100px;           
}
```

Comment: У Вас класс clear, а вы в css пишете как для id.

Comment: Может overflow:hidden; для блока куда будете вводить текст, не? Или я не так понял)

Comment: @Ifexe вопрос настолько древний, что автор почти наверняка не ответит. Попробуйте какой-нибудь из новых вопросов. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, как обычно, банальна) Тег `<script>` имеет обязательный закрывающий тег: `</script>`, вот и всё)

А предыдущий ответ не считаю верным. Такое впечатление, что надо было просто что-то ответить.

Comment: Если бы ошибка была в незакрытом теге - на экран вообще ничего не показалось бы. Автор вопроса видимо по ошибке не закрыл тег, когда публиковал сообщение сюда.

Comment: А вот здесь я с вами абсолютно согласен...

Comment: Да, он мог ошибиться, также как и указание `#class` вместо `.class`)) Также, как и свойство css `marging`, которое вы вряд ли встречали. Исправив все эти небольшие ошибки, я добился работы кода в своём браузере. В общем, в студии нужен автор.

Answer (score -1):

Одна из проблем сразу бросается в глаза - Вы везде жестко закрепляете ширину и высоту в `px`.

А ведь у пользователей могут быть разные мониторы ;)

Comment: Абсолютный бред ^^

Comment: Почему бред? Я правда не знаю, за что отвечает javascript, но если рассмотреть предложенную структуру оформления без скриптов, скажем, на нетбуке и на мониторе 19 дюймов при разных разрешениях, что Вы увидите в итоге? Попробуйте.

Comment: Потому что то, что написали вы, явно не имеет никакого отношения к заявленной проблеме.

Comment: Почему не имеет? Как раз и имеет. К примеру, ширина левой колонки `160рх`, а если пользователь введет в левую колонку одно слово, и его ширина в пикселях будет больше `160рх`? Что Вы увидите? Очень хорошо это наблюдается в браузере google chrome.

Comment: У вас каша в голове, причем тут google chrome? Прописывается max-width и текст уже не вылезет за заданные рамки... Или и с этим вы не согласны?<br>
Про google chrome вообще бред полный, не понял вообще к чему это было написано...

Comment: вот только что взял и прописал и что? а ничего. Это не решает проблему. а по поводу chrome, то он отображает границы колонок в отличии от ИЕ(при стилях автора). и тогда как раз видно как текст спокойно вылезает на соседнюю колонку. А каша наверное у Вас в голове, поскольку вместо того, чтобы спросить чего я делаю такие выводы - Вы начинаете оскорблять

Comment: Вы пишите о проблемах, которые известны только вам... Исходя именно из того, что такие проблемы (особенно что касается хрома) известны лишь вам, я и делаю выводы, что вы пишите о чем-то другом...<br>
Читая ваш ответ, возникло впечатление, что это ответ на какой-то другой вопрос, но никак не на этот...

Comment: ikot, выбор в пользу фиксированной или плавающей разметки - это не ошибка!это дело автора. в любом случае - отношения к решению вопроса это точно не имеет.да, на мониторах с большим разрешением может и глупо смотриться, но, по-моему, явно учиться пока и ему нет особой разницы как это будет смотреться на большом разрешении.
и, кстати, я проверил на Chrome. я наполнил блок большим количеством слов. у меня ничего за пределы блоков не выходит.

Comment: Да проблема не в большом количестве информации, а в длинных словах (писал немного выше) - они как раз выходят за границы. А в остальном я с Вами согласен.